# Regex to Remove Empty Line and Number

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am having trouble removing the number following an empty line using Regex. Here's the sample paragraph that I have:

```
1
- Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of

2
the printing and typesetting industry.

49
and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker.
```

I need to remove all the numbers from the beginning of the sentence as well as the empty lines:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker.
```

This is the regex that I can think of `[\n](.)` ,but it can only remove one digit of number

The difficult part is to remove the number because the number of digits are not necessary 1 or 2 digits. How do I tackle this problem?

Comment: Where are you using this regex?  Regex flavors matter.  Are you using something like Notepad++?

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong I parse it in jquery and also test it on https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a regex replace of the following regex with blank:

```
^\d*\n
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/7Kv9KQCo7Y6Jpz).